# Enumeration hasMoreElements() returns false

Tags: java, enumeration

I do this in my code:

```
            Enumeration liste = attribut.getListe ();
            if (liste != null) {
                while (liste.hasMoreElements ()) {
...
```

I have one element in my Enumeration but when I inspect `liste.hasMoreElements ()`, why does it return `false`?

Comment: How do you initialize `_listeAttrubts`?

Comment: Your code does not make sense.

Comment: should it be `_liste.hasMoreelements()` ?

Comment: sorry it's not _listeAttrubts but _liste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have `getListe()` always return a collection (empty or otherwise) and only use an Iterator.

e.g.

```
for(Entry e: getListe()) {
   // do something with e.
}
```

Instead of creating an empty list you can use [Collections.emptyList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) (and other empty collections)

If your Enumeration should have an element but doesn't, it would suggest you have a bug in getListe()

Answer (score 0):

Have you already iterated the enumeration? I.e. does getListe() return a new element list?

From the javadoc:

```
for (Enumeration e = v.elements() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
     System.out.println(e.nextElement());
 }
```

Comment: Enumeration is an iterator, an instance can only be iterated once.

Comment: How  can i do for iterated twice

Comment: Get another instance using the elements() method on the container. It is more common to do what @PeterLawrey suggested though.